# How to upload a file to pythonanywhere using react native?

Tags: pythonanywhere

I am trying to build an app through `react-native` wherein I need to upload a `JSON` file to my account folder hosted on `pythonanywhere`.

Can you please tell me how can I upload a `JSON` file to the `pythonanywhere` folder through `react-native`?

Answer (score 0):

The web framework that you're using will have documentation about how to create a view that can accept filee uploads. Then you can use the fetch API in your javascript to send the file to it.